# jQuery click() function within a for loop shows unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I would like to use the click() function of jQuery within a for loop in order to make three HTML elements clickable. I created a simple test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      function loadContent(){
        var values = ['a','b','c'];
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          var id = values[i];
          alert(id);
          $('#' + id).click(function() {
            function2(id);
          });
        }
      }

      function function2(id) {
        // do some fancy stuff like...
        alert(id);
      }

      loadContent();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map">
    <a id="a">a</a>
    <a id="b">b</a>
    <a id="c">c</a>
  </map>
</body>
```

As you can see, I would like to display the character 'a' if I click on 'a' (a), display 'b' while clicking on 'b', and so on. Unfortunately, the character 'c' is displayed while clicking on 'a'. No other events are triggered. I do not see the mistake I commit.

I don't bother if this code is efficient or not. I just want to know, why click() does not act as expected in this context. Thanks in advance for any hints or solution.

Comment: There should be a complete Stackexchange site devoted to this question :-)

Comment: **Why hasn't this made it to the JavaScript FAQ yet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- All your `id` attributes are set to `id="a"` so you're re-binding the first element each time (this is the main issue with your `click` handler).  Set the second to `id="b"` and the third to `id="c"`.
- `<script>` elements can't be self-closing, our jQuery include needs fixing from `/>` to `></script>`
- `</map>` should be `</div>`
- You're re-using `id` scoped to the function, but there's no need you might as well use `function2(this.id)` as the simplest fix for your case.

[You can test the updated/working version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zdvSG/2/).

Answer (score 2):

Each one of the "click" handlers you create will reference that same, **single** variable "id".  You'll note that it changes on each iteration of the loop. When the loop is done, it'll be pointing at the very last one.

You need to set up the handlers differently:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      var id = values[i];
      alert(id);
      $('#' + id).click((function(id) {
        return function() { function2(id); };
      })());
    }
```

The block constructed for your `for` loop does **not** create a new lexical scope, as it does in some languages. In Javascript, that "id" variable is a local variable to the "loadContent" function.  Each one of the "click" handlers in your version references that same variable.

Comment: This isn't the *only* issue, the `id` attributes are a problem as well.

Comment: Well it sure seems like it'd be the issue if the rest of the code weren't all broken. I assumed he just typed it in wrong. Why else would he always see "c"? *edit* - ah good edit :-)

Comment: yeah sorry you're correct this is also an issue, but not the simplest fix IMO, `this.id` would work in this case, and be cheaper :)

Comment: @Nick yes of course in this case that'd be true. Still, if that's how he fixed this one it'd take *another* SO question to confront the closure problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 elements with the same ID. An ID is supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

All of your id's are set to 'a'.  Try setting your id's to a,b,c

Answer (score 0):

The ids of the `<a></a>` tags are all "a" in your example.